# nlog configure field to output json with no escaping

Tags: .net-6.0, nlog

on a net 6.0 this code output log using nlog:

```
_LoggerService.LogEvent(LogLevel.Error,string.Format("Error: {0}, InnerException: {1}, StackTrace: {2}", error.Message, (error.InnerException != null ? error.InnerException.Message : string.Empty), error.StackTrace),
new
{
 host = context.Request.Host,
 refer = context.Request.Headers.Referer,
 path = context.Request.Path,
 method = context.Request.Method,
 body = requestBody
},error);
```

requestBody is a string containing json, i would like to write into the file as json without escaping.

this the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\temp\log\log.json" >
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
        <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false" >
          <layout xsi:type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="20"/>
        </attribute>
      </layout>
    </target>

    <target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" 
              uri="http://xxx:8092" 
              index="xxx" 
              requireAuth="false"
              includeAllProperties="true">
        <field name="message" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="elastic" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="jsonFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

this the output on the log.json:

```
{ "time": "2023-05-09 10:29:27.2003", "level": "ERROR", "message": "Error: InvalidTokenException, InnerException: , StackTrace:    at DWA.Authentication.Controllers.DWAController`1.AuthorizeAsync(JObject oInputParams) in D:\\GIT\\DWA\\MAIN\\DWA.Authentication\\Controllers\\DWAController.cs:line 70\r\n   at BD.StaticQuery.DWA.Controllers.BDStaticQueryController.GetMongoSection(JObject oInputParams) in D:\\GIT\\DWA\\MAIN\\BD.StaticQuery.DWA\\Controllers\\BDStaticQueryController.cs:line 125\r\n   at lambda_method9(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at DWA.Framework.Middlewares.ErrorHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in D:\\GIT\\DWA\\MAIN\\DWA.Framework\\Middlewares\\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 32", "eventProperties": { "environment": "Development", "data": {"host":{"Value":"localhost:44324", "HasValue":true, "Host":"localhost", "Port":44324}, "refer":["https://localhost:44324/index.html"], "path":{"Value":"/api/BD.StaticQuery.BDStaticQueryServiceREST.svc/GetMongoSection", "HasValue":true}, "method":"POST", "body":"{\"parameters\":{\"nameSection\":\"home_smart\",\"staticToken\":\"\"},\"token\":\"geZgfRZH2lUZJikdwXpJpie6iQDIHG9/ielFmXyDT4LGbki2gw+pEkeHgJuYVQlBzxjSyjKGow3cbfTaIuhrncg2851/XMiEs8Prs+WZVtkRY7QLxQV9qD5RfJvhlGMN947SW49RIMS0wJws+c9GytJBSylAYKOabAQkpMgP3P8wEOuQoonKPMzXImzeMhG7CvotONOnjOH9eaODChm+rx9wOit6i8SsBXTZQOGHHxaHPJehhil0Tw+p9kzX9lGxYYc1ViYeo7ROBd1aAveOprjL43191AMn/QV0XeR35EITgicLJtlXei1K1T7uTQUg2ENoSe0blVNzrLu53dTLxfll9ao1vyDCP5SwUQF5i+wlDc9IVwjEdHZtoI5S4JY5C5cRPSyd+FCNzCPLilQ2+UGqQJvzoda1PXcBDCWx2SaEQ01X1db5W5MQIx82xlvwQWGzlYq+k69sP69IFQTbG/27VvVDupT2VPPyfciM9EE=\n\"}"} } }
```

actually the body field is string, i would like to change to json, i want change "body":"xxx"
to "body":{....}
how to do it?

today 15-05 made this changes but still doesn't work

to write log:

```
_LoggerService.LogEvent(
                    LogLevel.Error,
                    string.Format("Error: {0}, InnerException: {1}, StackTrace: {2}", error.Message, (error.InnerException != null ? error.InnerException.Message : string.Empty), error.StackTrace),
                     new
                     {
                         host = context.Request.Host,
                         refer = context.Request.Headers.Referer,
                         path = context.Request.Path,
                         method = context.Request.Method,
                         body = requestBody
                     },
                    error);
```

the nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\temp\log\dwa\dwa_web.json" >
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
        <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false" >
          <layout xsi:type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true" excludeProperties="jsonbody">
            <attribute name="body" layout="${event-properties:item=jsonbody}" encode="false" />
          </layout>
        </attribute>
        <!--
       <layout xsi:type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="20"/>
          <layout xsi:type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true" exclude="jsonbody"  maxRecursionLimit="20">
            <attribute name="body" layout="${event-properties:item=jsonbody}" encode="false" />
          </layout>
         -->
      </layout>
    </target>

    <target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" 
              uri="http://onlivelogger01.online.gruppo24.net:8092" 
              index="dwa" 
              requireAuth="false"
              includeAllProperties="true">
        <field name="message" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="elastic" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="jsonFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

output:

```
{ "time": "2023-05-15 10:46:45.1404", "level": "ERROR", "message": "Error: token scaduto o non valido!, InnerException: , StackTrace:    at DWA.Authentication.Controllers.DWAController`1.AuthorizeAsync(JObject oInputParams) in D:\\GIT\\DWA\\MAIN\\DWA.Authentication\\Controllers\\DWAController.cs:line 70\r\n   at BD.StaticQuery.DWA.Controllers.BDStaticQueryController.GetMongoSection(JObject oInputParams) in D:\\GIT\\DWA\\MAIN\\BD.StaticQuery.DWA\\Controllers\\BDStaticQueryController.cs:line 125\r\n   at lambda_method9(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at DWA.Framework.Middlewares.ErrorHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in D:\\GIT\\DWA\\MAIN\\DWA.Framework\\Middlewares\\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 32", "eventProperties": { "environment": "Local", "data": {"host":"localhost:44324", "refer":[], "path":"/api/BD.StaticQuery.BDStaticQueryServiceREST.svc/GetMongoSection", "method":"POST", "body":"{\"parameters\":\n{\"word\":\"decreto%20lesislativo\",\"rows\":\"5\"}\n,\"token\":\"geZgfRZH2lUZJikdwXpJpoh2oJsFxD1a5cXi+EmeHoUvS7/34WiEIKVVIs8IaJc9sbMKNuGnwcNwVVXRsJoI7teEXSiwgPxJQBsb9qkTI9wY346pVZ2nFeonZbLnazlkuqrNhoWpd0ETQ9rTOXnSIrXIG+gk7BrfDDRzWn43OyFrtMYA3ksH1NPjzBaOqeZPqrxDJ1arVSVWido/MkrEvvErNoQji+iE4zKjCMoV1GlOJA0z5VWvyrEfKsvBIBlYhE/Ur2FJEPezC0zhBqJO6sIdG7YHiqRtqZWZjdCWN9DO7sj2YUvDXJ8MLr7vaReKbAW+uW1pm5Lw7aBMeXP69H4edKPO6n/lfK5C6cfb48QMYIqkci9aYpwS09pGV/DgqeKP0wvtux6uph+CeKbkbsO9gpAMSLXcNOTBs9X6qwusf0tYnqJDcq9ewgnZRmsAALRTqurY2GhWx70Rwbw3TGJRR2DlEEqhWT71SFjOgLQ=\"}"} } }
```

Comment: The `loggerService` with `LogEvent` looks very home-baked. Any reason for not using NLog `Logger` directly or Microsoft `ILogger` ? Need more details about the implementation of `LoggerService.LogEvent` to guess how to make it handle structured logging with property-names. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging and https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging

Answer (score 0):

If you use property-name `"jsonbody"` when json-string (Checking `ContentType`), and when non-json then use the property-name `"body"`. Then you can do this:

```xml
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
        <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false" >
          <layout xsi:type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true" excludeProperties="jsonbody">
              <attribute name="body" layout="${event-properties:item=jsonbody}" encode="false" />
          </layout>
        </attribute>
      </layout>
```

Where `"<attribute name="eventProperties">` will `excludeProperties="jsonbody"`-property-name when listing all properties, and then explicit specify that `jsonbody` should not be encoded as json-string.

Comment: still escaped, i noticed path field is not escaped, maybe it does not recognize the content of jsonbody as json.

Comment: this works too change body = requestBody to body = JObject.Parse(requestBody)

Comment: Think you ignored my first step about changing property-name to `"jsonbody"` depending on `ContentType`. But just continued to always use `"body"` as property-name. But yes parsing the json-document (using `JObject`), then NLog can render the content of the json-document.

Comment: I changed the name to jsonbody but it's still the same. i think it checks the type if string create string field, if object create json

Comment: @FDB NLog doesn't check anything when using string-values. Do you provide the string-value when using `"jsonbody"` or have you now changed to `JObject` ? (Notice that my initial suggestion expected that `"jsonbody"` was standard string-value)

Comment: First solution dies'nt work, jsonbody element Is created as string

Comment: @FDB There is no `jsonBody`-element. There is `<attribute name="body"` with `encode="false"` that skips all json-string-encoding. And there is `exclude="jsonbody"`.

Comment: @FDB Notice that you should only insert one property-name. Either `"jsonBody"` or `"body"`, depending on `ContentType` not both at the same time.

Comment: i renamed body to jsonbody in _LoggerService.LogEvent(.....) and then made changes in nlog.config as suggested. but the output does'nt change

Comment: @FDB Sorry about the confusion. I added `throwConfigExceptions="true"` and then noticed that the correct option-name is `excludeProperties` (and not `exclude`). I have updated the answer with the fixed names